# How can I skip a column when using getRange() - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cant seem to figure out how to put this script to skip column `L`. I tried many different varieties but all result in error. I hope somebody with more experience can shed light. I need `I:K` and `M:O` without `L`.

```
sheet1.getRange("I1:O"+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a simpl modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet1.getRange("I1:O"+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues()
```

#### To:

```
sheet1.getRange("I1:O"+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([i,j,k,,m,n,o]) => [i,j,k,m,n,o]);
```

or

```
sheet1.getRange("I1:O"+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues().map(([i,j,k,,...mno]) => [i,j,k,...mno]);
```

#### Note:

- Please use this modified script with enabling V8 runtime.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 2):

**Another approach:**

```
const array = sheet1.getRange('I1:O'+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
array.forEach(a => a.splice(3, 1));
```

In more detail, `3` is chosen because, starting from `0`, `L` is at the third position: `I, J, K, L`.

**Code snippet:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const array = sheet1.getRange('I1:O'+sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  array.forEach(a => a.splice(3, 1));
  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: I think that it is also a good solution. When the size of array is large, when `splice` is used, the memory for running Google Apps Script can be saved.

Comment: @Tanaike To help me better understand your comment, do you mean that the script from soMario, is... [A] better for larger array size? or [B] worse for larger array size? Thank you :)

Comment: @JamesReed68 About your question, for example, when a large array size is used in a loop when only one array is used, there is that an error related to the memory occurs. In this case, I think that when `splice` is used for the array, such an error becomes difficult to occur. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your detailed answer. I learned a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: @JamesReed68 Welcome. When my comment was useful, I'm glad.