# Google App Script: Find & Replace for specific columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

##### Here is the problem & logic for the find & replace script I am using.

- Search Sheet for `to_replace` string.

  - If found, replace `to_replace` with `replace_with`.
  - If not found, replace `to_replace` with `to_replace` // This is not needed, and causes problems (it replaces all formulas, and replaces it with a string).

##### My Objective:

I would like the script to only replace cells that match `to_replace`, and ignore every other cell.

##### My Rookie Solution:

Exclude specific columns in the foruma by eliminating column C from array using script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209382/how-can-i-skip-a-column-when-using-getrange-google-apps-script/65209569?noredirect=1#comment124971757_65209569). (only find & replace within Column B & D).

Here is the modified code I added in My Current Script...

```
const range = sheet.getRange('B2:D'+lastRow).getValues();
range.forEach(a => a.splice(1, 1)); //removes column C.
```

But I get the error: "TypeError: var data  = range.getValues(); is not a function"

##### Question

Can you help me troubleshoot my rookie solution, or teach me a better way to solve this problem?

---

##### My current script

```
function findAndReplace(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()
  // var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn) //REMOVED - Searches all columns.

  const range = sheet.getRange('B2:D'+lastRow).getValues(); //ADDED - Searches only B & D
  range.forEach(a => a.splice(1, 1)); //ADDED - Searches only B & D
     
  var to_replace = "TextToFind";
  var replace_with = ""; //Leave blank to delete Text, or enter text in quotes to add string.
  var data  = range.getValues();
 
    var oldValue="";
    var newValue="";
    var cellsChanged = 0;
 
    for (var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
      for (var i=0; i<data[r].length; i++) {
        oldValue = data[r][i];
        newValue = data[r][i].toString().replace(to_replace, replace_with);
        if (oldValue!=newValue)
        {
          cellsChanged++;
          data[r][i] = newValue;
        }
      }
    }
    range.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `teach me a better way to solve this problem`, in your situation, I thought that when TextFinder is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced. When TextFinder is used for achieving your goal, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var to_replace = "TextToFind";
  var replace_with = ""; //Leave blank to delete Text, or enter text in quotes to add string.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var ranges = ['B2:B' + lastRow, 'D2:D' + lastRow];
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().forEach(r => 
    r.createTextFinder(to_replace).matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith(replace_with)
  );
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to replace the part of cell value, please modify `r.createTextFinder(to_replace).matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith(replace_with)` to `r.createTextFinder(to_replace).replaceAllWith(replace_with)`.
- As an additional modification, if your script is modified, how about the following modification?

  ```
    function findAndReplace() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
      var range = sheet.getRange('B2:D' + lastRow);
      var data = range.getValues();
      var to_replace = "TextToFind";
      var replace_with = ""; //Leave blank to delete Text, or enter text in quotes to add string.
      for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data[r].length; i++) {
          var value = data[r][i].toString();
          if (i != 1 && value.includes(to_replace)) {
            data[r][i] = data[r][i].replace(to_replace, replace_with);
          }
        }
      }
      range.setValues(data);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Thank you for this Pro Alternative. It works very fast, and is 100% accurate. Tanaike, you are amazing at Google App Scripts. You have the answer to every one of my questions. I learn so much from you, and am inspired to one day be as good as you.

Comment: @JamesReed68 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. And also, when you got something from my answer, I'm glad.

Comment: I also tested the modifications that you suggested for  my existing script `As an additional modification, if your script is modified, how about the following modification?` and that is also working, and does not interfere with other columns. But this version is slower, and also updates every cell in the column. I will use your Pro Alternative, its more accurate :)

Comment: @JamesReed68 Thank you for testing it again. In the current stage, I think that the process cost of TextFinder is lower than that of other methods using the Spreadsheet service. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/09/30/benchmark-process-costs-for-searching-values-in-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/)

Comment: Wow, you did a very good job at investigating process cost. I learned a lot from that article. Thank you for sharing that essential resource!